# POST запрос в .net (из python в C#)

Tags: c#, .net, api

Переделываю POST запрос из python в c#.

В Python запрос выглядит так

```py
import requests 

config = {
    'client_id': 'dmitry@mail.no:portal',
    'client_secret': 'strong_pass_here',
    'token_url': 'https://host.com/connect/token'
}

def get_token():
    req = requests.post(config['token_url'],
    data={
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': config['client_id'],
        'client_secret': config['client_secret'],
        'scope': 'api'
    },
    headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
    return req.json()
```

Работает отлично, токены поучаю.

То же самое пытаюсь сделать в `c#`

```cs
public void GetToken()
        {
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                client_id = clientId,
                client_secret = clientSecret,
                grant_type = "client_credentials",
                scope = "api"
            });

            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(token_URL);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(jsonData);
            req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Close();

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
```

При отправке получаю 400 ошибку.

Что надо поправить для получения положительного результата?

**UPD** запрос через `HttpClient` дает тоже 400 ошибку

```cs
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    StringContent cont = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PostAsync(token_URL, cont).Result;
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

результат

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Pragma: no-cache
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
  Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2022 09:00:18 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}
```

Comment: используйте HttpClient

Comment: @Konst ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var content = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
content.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
content.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId));
content.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", client_secret));
content.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "api"));
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, token_URL) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content) };
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Comment: Да, так получил 200 ответ. Есть понимание что не так было у меня в запросах?

Comment: содержимое в виде json пытались отправить через HttpClient,а метод api принимал form

Comment: Не стоит создавать HttpClient на каждый запрос, если конечно запросов больше, чем один. Об этом сказано в документации по классу. А еще не стоит игнорить `IDisposable`.